# FFmpeg: color distortion (Skewed lines) after converting to H.265 HEVC

Tags: android, ffmpeg, h.264, android-video-player, h.265

I converted a H264 video to a H265 video by ffmpeg with this [command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65523734/6133481) 
`ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v libx265 -vtag hvc1 output.mp4`

the output file is playing well on my windows machine, but when I play the file in an Allwinner powered (cpu: A64) Android device, the video grays out, and colors are shown in skewed (diagonal) lines. see the Image below:
[image: skewed color]

it seems that the color is a separate layer from the video frames and its resolution doesn't match the frames.

 and this is the files properties:
[image: diff files]

I run the command

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v libx265 -vtag hvc1 -t 1 -report -y test.mp4
```

and here is the log file:

```
ffmpeg started on 2022-02-27 at 17:24:29
Report written to "ffmpeg-20220227-172429.log"
Log level: 48
Command line:
ffmpeg -i inputH264.mp4 -c:v libx265 -vtag hvc1 -t 1 -report -y test.mp4
ffmpeg version 4.4.1-full_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 11.2.0 (Rev1, Built by MSYS2 project)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-lzma --enable-libsnappy --enable-zlib --enable-librist --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libzvbi --enable-librav1e --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-libass --enable-frei0r --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-libglslang --enable-vulkan --enable-opencl --enable-libcdio --enable-libgme --enable-libmodplug --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libshine --  libavutil      56. 70.100 / 56. 70.100
  libavcodec     58.134.100 / 58.134.100
  libavformat    58. 76.100 / 58. 76.100
  libavdevice    58. 13.100 / 58. 13.100
  libavfilter     7.110.100 /  7.110.100
  libswscale      5.  9.100 /  5.  9.100
  libswresample   3.  9.100 /  3.  9.100
  libpostproc    55.  9.100 / 55.  9.100
Splitting the commandline.
Reading option '-i' ... matched as input url with argument 'inputH264.mp4'.
Reading option '-c:v' ... matched as option 'c' (codec name) with argument 'libx265'.
Reading option '-vtag' ... matched as option 'vtag' (force video tag/fourcc) with argument 'hvc1'.
Reading option '-t' ... matched as option 't' (record or transcode "duration" seconds of audio/video) with argument '1'.
Reading option '-report' ... matched as option 'report' (generate a report) with argument '1'.
Reading option '-y' ... matched as option 'y' (overwrite output files) with argument '1'.
Reading option 'test.mp4' ... matched as output url.
Finished splitting the commandline.
Parsing a group of options: global .
Applying option report (generate a report) with argument 1.
Applying option y (overwrite output files) with argument 1.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Parsing a group of options: input url inputH264.mp4.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an input file: inputH264.mp4.
[NULL @ 00000000005150c0] Opening 'inputH264.mp4' for reading
[file @ 0000000000516b40] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto,data'
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 00000000005150c0] Format mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 probed with size=2048 and score=100
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 00000000005150c0] ISO: File Type Major Brand: isom
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 00000000005150c0] Unknown dref type 0x206c7275 size 12
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 00000000005150c0] Processing st: 0, edit list 0 - media time: 6000, duration: 7505000
...
...
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 00000000005150c0] stts: 7503000 ctts: 1000, ctts_index: 7500, ctts_count: 7503
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 00000000005150c0] stts: 7504000 ctts: 2000, ctts_index: 7501, ctts_count: 7503
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 00000000005150c0] stts: 7505000 ctts: 5000, ctts_index: 7502, ctts_count: 7503
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 00000000005150c0] Offset DTS by 6000 to make first pts zero.
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 00000000005150c0] Setting codecpar->delay to 2 for stream st: 0
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 00000000005150c0] Unknown dref type 0x206c7275 size 12
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 00000000005150c0] Processing st: 1, edit list 0 - media time: -1, duration: 432
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 00000000005150c0] Processing st: 1, edit list 1 - media time: 0, duration: 14400528
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 00000000005150c0] Before avformat_find_stream_info() pos: 17133382 bytes read:272238 seeks:1 nb_streams:2
[h264 @ 0000000000517ac0] nal_unit_type: 7(SPS), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0000000000517ac0] nal_unit_type: 8(PPS), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0000000000517ac0] nal_unit_type: 6(SEI), nal_ref_idc: 0
[h264 @ 0000000000517ac0] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0000000000517ac0] Format yuv420p chosen by get_format().
[h264 @ 0000000000517ac0] Reinit context to 720x400, pix_fmt: yuv420p
[h264 @ 0000000000517ac0] no picture 
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 00000000005150c0] All info found
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 00000000005150c0] After avformat_find_stream_info() pos: 1597 bytes read:305006 seeks:2 frames:5
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'inputH264.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.76.100
  Duration: 00:05:00.20, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 456 kb/s
  Stream #0:0(und), 4, 1/25000: Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 710x400, 402 kb/s, 24.99 fps, 25 tbr, 25k tbn, 180k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #0:1(per), 1, 1/48000: Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 48 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
Successfully opened the file.
Parsing a group of options: output url test.mp4.
Applying option c:v (codec name) with argument libx265.
Applying option vtag (force video tag/fourcc) with argument hvc1.
Applying option t (record or transcode "duration" seconds of audio/video) with argument 1.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an output file: test.mp4.
[file @ 000000000051e2c0] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto,data'
Successfully opened the file.
detected 4 logical cores
[h264 @ 00000000025e9a40] nal_unit_type: 7(SPS), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 00000000025e9a40] nal_unit_type: 8(PPS), nal_ref_idc: 3
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> hevc (libx265))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:0 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:0 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[h264 @ 00000000025e9a40] nal_unit_type: 6(SEI), nal_ref_idc: 0
[h264 @ 00000000025e9a40] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 00000000025e9a40] Format yuv420p chosen by get_format().
[h264 @ 00000000025e9a40] Reinit context to 720x400, pix_fmt: yuv420p
[h264 @ 00000000025e9a40] no picture 
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:0 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[h264 @ 00000000025e9ec0] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 2
[h264 @ 00000000025e9ec0] no picture 
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:0 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[h264 @ 00000000025ea640] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 2
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:0 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[h264 @ 0000000002588a80] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 0
[graph_1_in_0_1 @ 0000000003aea040] Setting 'time_base' to value '1/48000'
[graph_1_in_0_1 @ 0000000003aea040] Setting 'sample_rate' to value '48000'
[graph_1_in_0_1 @ 0000000003aea040] Setting 'sample_fmt' to value 'fltp'
[graph_1_in_0_1 @ 0000000003aea040] Setting 'channel_layout' to value '0x3'
[graph_1_in_0_1 @ 0000000003aea040] tb:1/48000 samplefmt:fltp samplerate:48000 chlayout:0x3
[format_out_0_1 @ 0000000003aeb9c0] Setting 'sample_fmts' to value 'fltp'
[format_out_0_1 @ 0000000003aeb9c0] Setting 'sample_rates' to value '96000|88200|64000|48000|44100|32000|24000|22050|16000|12000|11025|8000|7350'
[AVFilterGraph @ 00000000026fdb00] query_formats: 5 queried, 12 merged, 0 already done, 0 delayed
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:0 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:0 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:0 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[h264 @ 0000000002589600] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 0
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:0 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:0 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:0 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[h264 @ 00000000025e9a40] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 2
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:0 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:0 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[h264 @ 00000000025e9ec0] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 2
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0000000002589fc0] Setting 'video_size' to value '710x400'
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0000000002589fc0] Setting 'pix_fmt' to value '0'
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0000000002589fc0] Setting 'time_base' to value '1/25000'
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0000000002589fc0] Setting 'pixel_aspect' to value '0/1'
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0000000002589fc0] Setting 'frame_rate' to value '25/1'
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0000000002589fc0] w:710 h:400 pixfmt:yuv420p tb:1/25000 fr:25/1 sar:0/1
[format @ 0000000003de99c0] Setting 'pix_fmts' to value 'yuv420p|yuvj420p|yuv422p|yuvj422p|yuv444p|yuvj444p|gbrp|yuv420p10le|yuv422p10le|yuv444p10le|gbrp10le|yuv420p12le|yuv422p12le|yuv444p12le|gbrp12le|gray|gray10le|gray12le'
[AVFilterGraph @ 00000000026ff680] query_formats: 5 queried, 4 merged, 0 already done, 0 delayed
Output #0, mp4, to 'test.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.76.100
  Stream #0:0(und), 0, 1/12800: Video: hevc (hvc1 / 0x31637668), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 710x400, q=2-31, 25 fps, 12800 tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
      encoder         : Lavc58.134.100 libx265
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: N/A
  Stream #0:1(per), 0, 1/48000: Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
      encoder         : Lavc58.134.100 aac
Clipping frame in rate conversion by 0.000008
frame=    1 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.07 bitrate=   4.8kbits/s speed=3.14x    
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[h264 @ 00000000025ea640] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 0
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[h264 @ 0000000002588a80] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 0
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[h264 @ 0000000002589600] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 2
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[h264 @ 00000000025e9a40] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 2
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[h264 @ 00000000025e9ec0] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 0
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[h264 @ 00000000025ea640] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 0
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[h264 @ 0000000002588a80] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 2
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[h264 @ 0000000002589600] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 2
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[h264 @ 00000000025e9a40] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 0
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[h264 @ 00000000025e9ec0] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 0
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[h264 @ 00000000025ea640] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 2
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[h264 @ 0000000002588a80] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 2
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[h264 @ 0000000002589600] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 0
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[h264 @ 00000000025e9a40] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 0
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[h264 @ 00000000025e9ec0] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 2
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[h264 @ 00000000025ea640] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 2
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[h264 @ 0000000002588a80] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 0
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[h264 @ 0000000002589600] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 0
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[h264 @ 00000000025e9a40] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 2
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[h264 @ 00000000025e9ec0] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 2
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[h264 @ 00000000025ea640] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 0
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[h264 @ 0000000002588a80] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 0
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[h264 @ 0000000002589600] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 2
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[h264 @ 00000000025e9a40] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 2
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[h264 @ 00000000025e9ec0] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 0
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[out_0_0 @ 0000000003de85c0] EOF on sink link out_0_0:default.
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:1] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:1] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[out_0_1 @ 0000000003aeb8c0] EOF on sink link out_0_1:default.
No more output streams to write to, finishing.
[aac @ 000000000051dc40] Trying to remove 136 more samples than there are in the queue
frame=   25 fps=0.0 q=35.4 Lsize=      20kB time=00:00:00.99 bitrate= 163.6kbits/s speed=2.26x    
video:2kB audio:14kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:2kB muxing overhead: 30.161892%
Input file #0 (inputH264.mp4):
  Input stream #0:0 (video): 32 packets read (2030 bytes); 27 frames decoded; 
  Input stream #0:1 (audio): 53 packets read (8202 bytes); 53 frames decoded (54272 samples); 
  Total: 85 packets (10232 bytes) demuxed
Output file #0 (test.mp4):
  Output stream #0:0 (video): 25 frames encoded; 25 packets muxed (1658 bytes); 
  Output stream #0:1 (audio): 47 frames encoded (47992 samples); 48 packets muxed (13908 bytes); 
  Total: 73 packets (15566 bytes) muxed
80 frames successfully decoded, 0 decoding errors
[AVIOContext @ 000000000051e380] Statistics: 2 seeks, 4 writeouts
[aac @ 000000000051dc40] Qavg: 65393.609
[AVIOContext @ 000000000051edc0] Statistics: 305006 bytes read, 2 seeks
```

Comment: Does the HEVC file play normally when you play it on a desktop video player (e.g. VLC)?

Comment: @RonaldS.Bultje as I mentioned in the question, Yes! The file play normally on my windows machine, but have this issue playing on an Android device powered by Allwinner A64 cpu.

Comment: Indeed, sorry, I didn't read that correctly the first time. That suggests the issue is not in the file, but in the player. Second question then: is this specific to only certain resolutions? You can rescale while transcoding using `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v libx265 -vtag hvc1 -vf scale=W:H output.mp4`. For other W/H combinations (e.g. 720x480), does it work correctly (on the Android device)?

Comment: My guess is that 710x400 resolution is not supported. Assuming the player uses hardware acceleration for decoding, the resolution must be a multiple of 16 in each axis (or even a multiple of 32 in some cases).

Comment: sidenote, kind of a cool visual effect